# Ease of Access Center opens when I try to open On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: c#, .net

So when I try to open the On-Screen Keyboard in C# with

```
Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

it opens the Ease of Access Center program (at least 2-3 windows) and the On-Screen Keyboard. This does not happen when I run the On-Screen Keyboard program from Windows Explorer.

My C# program details:
Compiled for x86.

My PC details:
Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Win 8.1 x86 in PowerShell, so it's either a problem with some other part of your code, a 32-bit/64-bit issue, or something specific to your computer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I also cannot reproduce that in Visual Studio 2013 targeting .NET 4.5.3 x86 / x64

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was my code. I think my code may have started the process multiple times, and that is why the Ease of Access Center program opened (2-3 times). Sorry about that.
                    @JohnSaunders Thank you for notifying me about that.